# How does select formula in C# work using reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, filtering

I would like to ask a question about the following function related to reports in C#.

```
crystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "{Cars.CarCode} = " + CarCode;
```

Does this formula add a filter condition to the current query code that is used in the report, or does it create a whole new query?

If not is there an other method of further filtering a report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will add a filter condition to the query. If carcode is a string you need to change it to :

```
crystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = string.Format("{Cars.CarCode} = '{0}'",CarCode);
```